# VLC : How to change a certain key color of video with a background image?

Tags: vlc

I am struggling to find the necessary vlc command line arguments and vlm file   setting for the following problem:

1. Given an mp4 video with blue background
2. Replace the blue color, with showing an image on the background
3. Save the result to an mp4 with sound also

VLC documentation is too poor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put vlc folder in the PATH (Not necessary but saves some lines of code.)

Open a Windows  Command Line as "ADMISTRATOR" (right click and select) give this in command prompt:

```
vlc -I dummy --vlm-conf=mosaic3.vlm -vv --sub-filter=mosaic --mosaic-alpha=255 --mosaic-width=960 --mosaic-height=540 --mosaic-xoffset=0 --mosaic-yoffset=0 --mosaic-keep-picture --bluescreen-u=120 --bluescreen-v=90 --bluescreen-vt=17 --bluescreen-ut=17 --file-logging --logfile=".\log.txt" --logmode=text
```

where mosaic3.vlm is a file as follows

```
new channel1 broadcast enabled
setup channel1 input myvideo.mp4
setup channel1 output #duplicate{dst=mosaic-bridge{height=540,width=960,chroma=YUVA,vfilter=bluescreen},select=video,dst=bridge-out{id=11},select=audio,acodec=mp4a,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:display
  
new mosaic broadcast enabled
setup mosaic input "back.jpg"
setup mosaic option image-duration=-1
setup mosaic output #transcode{sfilter=mosaic{height=540,width=960,cols=1,rows=1,keep-aspect-ratio=enabled,keep-picture=1},vcodec=h264,acodec=mp4a,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:bridge-in:std{access=file,mux=ts,dst=myoutput.mp4}

control channel1 play
control mosaic play
```

Your result will be saved at myoutput.mp4

Options:

- My video is 960 x 540 , replace with your own dimensions
- Chroma key
  bluescreen-u=120 --bluescreen-v=90     corresponds to blue color

If you have a green, the try :      bluescreen-u=60 --bluescreen-v=45

See here for other colors: https://www.mikekohn.net/file_formats/yuv_rgb_converter.php